# JQuery Validation: errorPlacement doesn't get called

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I use the jquery validation plugin. However, the errorPlacement function won't be executed. No console logging happens if validation errors occur. What to do?
I use jquery 1.10.3, I tried 1.9.0 as well.

```
$("#rateform").validate({
    debug: true,
    rules: {
      stars: {
      required: true,
      min: 1
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
      console.log(element);
    }
}

});
```

Comment: Use messages:{} after rules: {}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clean up your code

```
$("#rateform").validate({
    debug: true,
    rules: {
        stars: {
            required: true,
            min: 1
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            console.log(element);
        }
    }

});
```

Is errorPlacement supposed to be in rules. Looking at the [documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/), that is not how it seems to work.

```
$("#rateform").validate({
    debug: true,
    rules: {
        stars: {
            required: true,
            min: 1
        }
    },
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        console.log(element);
    }    
});
```

Comment: Yes you're right, I placed one bracket wrong. Unfortunately, it didn't show any error messages :/

Comment: @AndiPower, By design, the plugin ignores non-existent elements defined within `rules`.  Since you put `errorPlacement` within `rules`, it just looks like a field named `errorPlacement`... there's no matching field, then it's simply ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I know this might seem obvious, but make sure you are not calling

```
var options = {}; //some different initial settings
$("#rateform").validate(options) ;
```

again on the page or in another script file ***AFTER*** you initialized it. This will ***WIPE OUT*** your previous options.

It's embarrassing I know, but I was debugging directly on the page (this allowed me to bypass build process) and had forgot that it was there.  I spent most of the day trying to figure out why my options were not being applied (which was in another script file that was included BEFORE the above call).

Hopefully, this will save others time coming to this realization in the future (including myself).